# Google Cloud Datastore - issue enabling Datastore Admin

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-platform

I created a project under google cloud platform (free trial account). I deployed my application using app engine and also loaded data into google  data store kind. I am planning to enable the data store admin of Google data store to create backups but for some reason the when i click Enable DataStore Admin getting the below error

```
" There was a Problem loading Datastore Admin. Please try again"
```

Is this error due to free trial account?.

Comment: Even I am facing the same issue, since yesterday. Did you find any solution?

Comment: no still having the issue

Comment: @Dan McGrath would you be able to take a look at this Dan

Comment: @Pravin  see the solution that worked for me

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the issue and it appears with datastore location set to useast1 when i created the project . Setting the datastore location to uscentral will resolve the issue. I reported the issue to Google Cloud Support team